# SQL Joins and Renaming columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, renaming

If I have three tables such as `dog`, `cat`, and `animal`, where a property of `animal` is `name`, how can I join `dog` and `cat` and return both names?

The structure would look something like this:

```
---Dog---
AnimalID char(9)
ChasesID char(9)


---Cat---
AnimalID char(9)


--Animal--
AnimalID char(9)
Name     char(20)
```

Where I want to join `Dog` and `Cat` on the ChasesID (references AnimalID in Cat table) and return the names of both animals from `Animal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do this way, but if you only want to get names of the animals you can try with something like this:

```
SELECT Animal.Name AS Name
FROM (SELECT AnimalID FROM Cat
      UNION
      SELECT AnimalID FROM Dog) AS AnimalsUnion
LEFT JOIN Animal
       ON Animal.AnimalID = AnimalsUnion.AnimalID
```

It should do the trick..

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins for this:

```
select ad.name as dogname, ac.name as chases
from dog d join
     animal ad
     on d.animalid = ad.animalid join
     animal ac
     on d.chasesid = ac.animalid;
```

From what I can tell, the `cat` table is superfluous.  It doesn't have a separate id, so you don't need it.  You can get the name directly from `animal`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a simple join over the three tables.

```
select c.column1,c.column2 , d.column1 , a.column1 from cat c, dog d, animal a where c.ChasesID = d.ChasesID and c.AnimalID = a.AnimalID;
```